# Make XTerm font bigger with no access to .bash_profile

Tags: linux, xterm

I have a `script.sh` that runs `xterm`, I do not have write access to `script.sh` , `.bash_profile` , I cannot change it.

I want to change the font size of xterm, I changed [~/.Xresources](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161652/how-to-change-the-default-font-size-of-xterm) as described. No effect.

I tried `alias xterm = "xterm -fa Monospace -fs 16"` , this works when I open an xterm, but when I execute `script.sh`, it does not work, (i.e. again it comes with default font. )

How can I increase the font size of `xterm` that runs inside a script that I cannot edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a short executable shell script called `xterm` in a directory somewhere where you can write, for example in `~/bin`.

The script should execute `xterm` with the options you want, and also with whatever options are passed from the caller:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

/usr/local/bin/xterm -fa Monospace -fs 16 "$@"
```

Replace the path above with the real path to `xterm` on your system (see the output of `command -v xterm`).

Then, call `script.sh` with an altered `PATH` variable:

```bash
PATH=~/bin:$PATH ./script.sh
```

... where `~/bin` is the path to the directory where you created your `xterm` script. By putting `~/bin` first in `PATH`, your script will be found before the real `xterm` executable when the `script.sh` script uses `xterm`.

This effectively overloads the `xterm` utility for the `script.sh` script.

This will *not* work if `script.sh` uses `xterm` with an absolute path, or if it resets the value of the `PATH` variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you *source* the script it will use your alias. Try `. script.sh` or `source script.sh` (they do the same thing).